# How to access a member of a struct which is passed into a function as pointer to pointer parameter?

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct addrinfo
{
    int ai_flags;
    int ai_family;
    int ai_socktype;
    int ai_protocol;
    size_t ai_addrlen;
    char *ai_canonname;
    struct sockaddr *ai_addr;
    struct addrinfo *ai_next;
} ADDRINFOA, *PADDRINFOA;
```

And I defined a function which accepts a pointer to pointer of type struct addrinfo and returns the value via "pointer reference"

```
void getAddress(addrinfo **addr){
     addr->ai_addr->sa_data = "0.0.0.0";   //sa_data is a member of ai_addr
}
```

I called a function getAddress using the following codes:

```
addrinfo *IPAddr = new addrinfo();
IPAddr->ai_addr = new sockaddr(); 
getAddress(&IPAddr);
```

I get an error:

> ```
> error: request for member 'ai_addr' in '* IPAddr ', which is of pointer type 'addrinfo*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
> *IPAddr ->ai_addr->sa_data[14] = {"10.10.10.10"};
> ```

Comment: Why are you passing a pointer to pointer as parameter when you only want to read from it?

Comment: it is just a practice function using pass by reference with pointer. This case is more trickier as I want to access a member struct of a parent struct and cannot used something like:
*pointer_to_pointer_parameter = &(a_value).

I want that whatever calling getAddress would have the value at pointer_to_pointer_parameter changed after the function getAddress is closed.

Comment: Pointer to a pointer usually implies that the function is going to allocate the structure (on the heap), initialise it's values and update the parameter to pass back the address of the newly allocated structure; ie a factory function.

Comment: `void getAddress( **addr)` is missing the type information for `addr`.

Comment: Also in C++ it's more idiomatic to actually pass by reference, e.g.: `void getAddress( addrinfo*& addr)` instead of passing pointer-to-pointer (which is the way to do it in C)

Comment: can someone just answer the question, which is just about syntax usage. My boss/teacher/president wants me to use pointer to pointer. and pass by reference to get the value returned from a function.

Comment: The question is answered. You forgot the type in `void getAddress(**addr)` and you have to dereference `addr` in the function. `addr` is a pointer to pointer. `addr->` is equivalent to `(*addr).`. `*addr` is a pointer to `addrinfo`. You need `(*addr)->`

Comment: I fixed the question by adding the type. I had the type in the code. If it was the type missing in the function declaration, it would have given a different error message.

Comment: @MinhPham if you have another homework type question that has some restrictions please mention these in the question.  If you don't people helping you will try to explain "best practice" and how the question could be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dereference `addr` (`*addr`) to get the `addrinfo*` back and you can't assign a C string directly to to the  `char[]` `sa_data`, you need to copy the C string into place.

Example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

void getAddress(addrinfo **addr){
    static const char zeroes[] = "0.0.0.0";
    std::copy_n(zeroes, std::size(zeroes), (*addr)->ai_addr->sa_data);
}
```

Note: According to [C++ Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) `*` (dereferencing) has lower precedence than `->` (member access) so we need to wrap `(*addr)` in parentheses in order to dereference `addr` in `(*addr)->ai_addr->sa_data`.

Comment: THANK YOU! you fixed 2 errors in 1 comments. In addition , would you clarify why *addr didn't work but (*addr) does ?

Comment: @MinhPham You're welcome. I added an explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`addr->ai_addr` is equivalent to `(*addr).ai_addr` but `(*addr)` returns a pointer to `addrinfo`. That's what the error message is telling you. You can't access a member from a pointer. You have to dereference `addr` twice, e.g.  `(*addr)->ai_addr` or `(**addr).ai_addr`.

Comment: THANK YOU !  It fixed. In addition, would you explain why  * addr->ai_addr->sa_data inside the function getAddress didn't work, but (*addr) does.

Comment: @MinhPham That's called [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). `->` has higher precedence than `*`. `*a->b` is equivalent to `*(a->b)` but you need `(*a)->b`